# Closing improperly closed h5py file

Tags: python-3.x, h5py

I wrote incorrect code that did not close some HDF files created with `h5py` before script termination. As such, attempting to read them in produces the following errors:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (bad local heap signature)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
<stacktrace removed>
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'DataStorage/0_-150.hdf5', errno = 17, error message = 'File exists', flags = 15, o_flags = c2)
```

when attempting to read it in with mode `a`. Is there a way to load in and "repair" the HDF file, or must I run the entire code (a large simulation) again?

Comment: How did you run the original code that opened the file? (from IDE, rune code from command window, command window interactively)? Running in the command window should free the resource. In the IDE, you can enter `f.close()` in the IDE command window (works in Spyder)

Comment: As a slurm job which was terminated by slurm, not me

Comment: I know nothing about slurm. HDF5 has a file locking mechanism when you open with write access (mode w or a). h5py supports this. So, the file is locked until the process releases it. My (limited) testing shows the file is release from command line processes. Does the slurm process ever stop/exit?

Comment: Yes - if the script terminates normally it is equivalent to `python myscript.py` terminating with exit code 0. If the process is terminated by slurm, however (equivalent to a non-zero exit code, typically if the process runs over requested walltime), as far as I can tell slurm doesn't do garbage collection so the file remains locked after the script terminates.